# Этимология слова исходя из контекста фразы

Tags: этимология

У меня вопрос по  этимологии слова "ТребоИсправление". Есть фраза "Журнал регистрации требоисправлений" мне никак не дается понимание ее. Спрашивал у заведующей кафедрой русской филологии Воронежского государственного университета она подтверждает ваши слова что вернее будет "требоСправление". Смотрел слово "исправить" в словаре церковно славянских слов. Его значение "возвести из одного состояния к другому" "изменить". Спрашивал у священника он говорит что "требоисправление" означает что треба исправляет человека над которым она совершается, очищает его, возводит его из одного состояния в другое. Может кто то может объяснить смысл фразы, есть ли специалисты по церковно славянскому языку?

Comment: А в каком контексте употреблялось слово?

Comment: На вахте духовной семинарии лежит журнал: "Журнал регистрации требоисправлений". В него записывают требы которые заказывают прихожане (освящения квартир, отпевания, причастие и пр.)

Answer (score 1):

Здесь не нужны специалисты по церковно-славянскому языку.  Обратимся к этимологии слова ПРАВИТЬ - многозначное слово, одно из значений- 
  ( http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/331818  )
Править что, исполнять или совершать, соблюдая должное. Править службу цареву, служить. Править поклон от кого, сказывать, отдавать по порученью. Править посольство,•стар. быть послом от царя. Править церковную службу, совершать по чину и обряду. Править кресты, отправлять великопостную службу на дому. Править именины, поминки, праздновать по обычаю.

От ПРАВИТЬ-справлять, исправлять. Исправлять - УСТАРЕВШЕЕ,ОФИЦИАЛЬНОЕ- исполнять какую-либо должность, обязанность ◆ Исправлять должность звонаря. ◆ Исправлять обязанности секретаря.( http://onega-krest.ru/saint-sacred/160-sanaksarskii.html  Прослужил о. Александр там всего несколько месяцев и 23 июля (5 августа) 1935 года был перемещен «исправлять обязанности для пополнения священнических треб по приходу села Соболево».У Ожегова даётся как второе значение, устаревшее. Т.е. в обиходной речи говорят "справлять требы", а в книжной-"исправлять требы". У старообрядцев только "исправлять", они строго придерживаются всех канонов, и в речи тоже. В церкви тоже стараются использовать книжные слова, лучше устаревшие.

Отсюда :"Требоисправления: крещение, причащение, исповедание грехов, сведение брачующихся, погребальные обряды, поминовение усопших, погребение"
http://obuk.ru/85253-obozrenie-permskogo-raskola-tak-nazyvaemogo-staroobryadchestva.html

Comment: Спасибо большое.